# Plot each point in a plotline from different files

Tags: gnuplot

I have 1000 files named "data_i.dat", i->(1,1000). Each file is of the format

```
1  0.311  0.422  0.011
2  0.455  0.111  0.431
.
.
.
```

and so on. Now, I want to plot a graph with 1000 points where each point is the number in the 352nd row and 2nd column from each file. Is there a way to do this?

I tried writing

```
plot for[i=0:1000] sprintf('data_%d.dat',i) every ::352::352
```

which I know is not the correct direction, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way to plot the data would probably be:

```
plot for [i=1:1000] sprintf("data_%d.dat",i) every ::351::351 u (i):2 w lp pt 7
```

However, a `plot for`-loop will plot the data from different files unconnected despite using `with linespoints`.
Furthermore, keep in mind row index starts with zero. So, line 352 requires `every ::351::351`.

So, my suggestion would be to collect the single datalines into a datablock first and then plot it connected `with linespoints`. Check `help with table` and `help datablocks`.

**Script:**

```
### plot single lines from many different files
reset session

myFile(i) = sprintf("data_%d.dat",i)

set table $Data
    plot for [i=1:1000] myFile(i) every ::351::351 u (i):2 w table
unset table

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7
### end of script
```